# Getting ACL values through ACL name via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, acl

Hope you guys are safe and healthy!

Can I ask if there is a way to use powershell to get the ACL based on the ACL name and extract the values out?

I am trying to compare the selected file or registry permissions with the ACL that I would be provided by user.

[image]

Example:
Inputs:

1. HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Test
2. ACL2 (name of ACL)

Output:
True (the permissions from input 1 matches the permissions in ACL2)
False (does match)

With these inputs, the script should get the permissions of the input 1 and compare to the permissions listed in ACL2.

What I am confused is, is there a list of ACLs that I can look for in Windows or through powershell?

Edit: Updated question.

Comment: So, let me rephrase your question - you want to list *some* paths that have given ACL?

Comment: @GrzegorzOchlik I would like to like to get the values inside the given ACL

Comment: Please show us some of the _"different ways"_ you have tried and explain what worked/didn't work. What is the example you're showing? The desired output? Some type of output for another script or application you need to parse out?

Comment: @Theo As of now, I am able to get the ACL of certain items such as the ACL of a register key through using Get-ACL. For getting and finding ACLs on Windows, I am having a little trouble trying to locate it. As for the example, 'acl2' is the name of the ACL, which the values will be used to compared to ACL of certain item such as a register key.

Comment: Again: what **IS** that picture you show?? Is that **input** to parse or is that your desired **output**. Where does the ACL name `ACL2` come from? An ACL you get with `Get-Acl` does not have a `Name` property, so this question remains totally unclear. Please explain what you need done

Comment: @plzSOS - Your edit doesn't clear anything up for me, perhaps for someone else it will but I would strongly suggest to add the **command** you are using that is generating that output.